# H-Bridge Sensing Voltage

Tags: h-bridge

While I was checking the [ST L298 H-bridge datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000240.pdf), I read that the voltage sensing of it is -1 to 2.3 V.

Can you please explain what is the meaning of sensing voltage?

Comment: Can you link the data sheet and say which page it's on.

Comment: No we can't, at least not without more information on what they mean by "voltage sensing" and what exactly is being sensed.  *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Comment: Ok Thnx 
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf
It is in page 2 , The Absolute Maximum Rating Table

Answer (score 2):

The figure -1 to 2.3V is an absolute limit and ideally it will be slightly positive (maybe 0.25V under load) if you are using sense resistors.

The sense pins on the device are when you need to connect a small value resistor to "check" the current drawn by the load on the H bridge. If you are not using these pins connect them to ground or the H bridge won't work. This ground connection takes the main load current so do it properly or you'll get problems.

Comment: Many Thanks 
I know that we need sense pins to connect them with PWM for changing the speed of my motor , right ?
the question , why i need to check the current drawn by the load ?

Comment: @EngSamara the chip is offering you the option to insert resistors (small values) that can be used by an external circuit for tripping the drives should the measured current be regarded as too high. If you don't have this feature short these pins to pin 8. I reckon some PWM drives will make use of this feature but not all.